# Groovy: Lombok @NoArgsConstructor not creating default constructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, lombok

I am using `lombok 1.18.6` in my spring boot project and I have `@NoArgsConstructor` but still am getting `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.validation.entity.Client; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.validation.entity.Client] with root cause`

Below is my `Client` entity

```
import lombok.AccessLevel
import lombok.Data
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode
import org.hibernate.annotations.Nationalized
import javax.persistence.CascadeType
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.OneToMany

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Entity
class Client implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id

    @Nationalized
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active

    @Nationalized
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String externalId

    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = RuleSet.class)
    private Set<RuleSet> ruleSets

    Client(String name, boolean active, String externalId){
        this.name = name
        this.active = active
        this.externalId = externalId
    }
}
```

Below is my `ClientRepository`

```
import com.validation.entity.Client
import com.validation.entity.RuleDefinition
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param

interface ClientRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Client, Long> {

    Client findByName(@Param("name")String name)

    Client findByNameIgnoreCase(@Param("name")String name)

    Client findByExternalId(@Param("lawId")String id)

    Client findByExternalIdIgnoreCase(@Param("lawId")String id)

    Client findByRuleSetsId(Long id)

    Set<Client> findByNameIgnoreCaseOrExternalIdIgnoreCase(@Param("name")String name,@Param("lawId")String id)

    Set<Client> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(@Param("name")String name)

}
```

Can someone please help me why am I getting `No default constructor for entity` even with `@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)`

Below is the full `stacktrace` when I make get request `https://localhost:9443/api/clients`

```
2019-03-22 11:46:44 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.validation.entity.Client; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.validation.entity.Client] with root cause
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.validation.entity.Client
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:673)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4946)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1666)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:569)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:388)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(PagingAndSortingRepositoryInvoker.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindAll(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below is the decompiled `Client` class

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Nationalized;

@Entity
public class Client
  implements Serializable, GroovyObject
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @Nationalized
  @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
  private String name;
  @Column(nullable=false)
  private boolean active;
  @Nationalized
  @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
  private String externalId;
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @OneToMany(targetEntity=RuleSet.class, mappedBy="client", cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
  private Set<RuleSet> ruleSets;

  public Client(String name, boolean active, String externalId)
  {
    MetaClass localMetaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();this.metaClass = localMetaClass;String str1 = name;this.name = ((String)ShortTypeHandling.castToString(str1));
    boolean bool = active;this.active = DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(Boolean.valueOf(bool));
    String str2 = externalId;this.externalId = ((String)ShortTypeHandling.castToString(str2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to: `BREAKING CHANGE: The in 1.16.22 introduced configuration key lombok.noArgsConstructor.extraPrivate is now false by default. Issue #1708`

Comment: `access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC` is redundant for `NoArgsConstructor`

Comment: @KarolDowbecki `access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC` added just to makesure that's not causing any issue

Comment: How are you building the project? Are other Lombok annotations like `@Getter` working?

Comment: its a gradle project, running it from `Intellij` I dont have  Lombok annotations on any other classes. I just started using `Lombok` library in my project and I hit a roadblock on very first Change I made on `Client` class

Comment: Why this is tagged Java when you are coding in Groovy?

Comment: Hmm..There is `com.wkelms.ebilling.validation.entity.Client` and `com.validation.entity.Client`? Just to be sure add also packages to you source snippets.

Comment: @pirho my bad, I have renamed all the instances when I posted the question, updated everything to `com.validation.entity.Client`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation error - Groovy and Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257162/compilation-error-groovy-and-lombok)

Comment: Can you check if replacing `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor` with `@Canonical` solves your problem?

Comment: What is the gain of adding lombok over what groovy already brings?

Answer (score 6):

Based on your de-compiled output you are using Groovy, not Java. [Lombok doesn't work well with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46258158/1602555). Your decompiled code shows this, there are no Lombok augmentations e.g. getters are not created by `@Data`.

If you plan to continue mixing Lombok with Groovy you need to revisit your project setup. Personally I'd not mix these two things.

Comment: Made `Client` class as `public` and still am getting the same exception

Comment: post the full stack trace. Also inspect the `.class` file with `javap -v` or de-lombok. This might be unrelated to Lombok, 1.18.6 works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this it helped to me for the `@NoArgsConstructor`. Now **lombok** works and no error displayed.

Add **Lombok** plugin besides dependency like this:

```
plugins {
  id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.4.1"
}
    
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
```

Have a nice day! Enjoy coding!

Comment: Check this link also https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not true that Lombok doesn't work well with Java, like stated above and in [Lombok doesn't work well with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257162/compilation-error-groovy-and-lombok/46258158#46258158).

There is no problem with consuming Lombok annotated Java Object in Groovy code, see also examples here
[here](https://github.com/chhex/groovylombok)

Lombok annotations in Groovy code are simply ignored. Groovy does not support Lombok annotations. So this more a issue of Groovy than visa versa.

That relativizes the statements not to use both. I think that's is the whole point of JVM based languages : the "relative"  good interoperability (Java, Groovy, JRuby, Kotlin etc).